# Coupon date for a monthly bond - excel

Tags: excel

I'm trying to calculate all the cash flows dates for a bond, the frequency date of the bond is monthly. For other frequency I usually use COUPNCD. I tried to use =EDATE(maturity date;-1) but the dates are not right since it's not considering the way coupons are paid, always the same day except when it doesn't exist.

**Example:**

Settlement date: 31-12-2014 ; Maturity date: 30-05-2016 ; Basis: 2 (actual/360) and Frequency: 4

Computing the coupon dates with =COUPNCD i get the following dates for the cash flows:

28-02-2015 30-05-2015 30-08-2015 **30-11-2015** 29-02-2016 30-05-2016

If I compute with =EDATE(date;-3) i get:

28-02-2015 30-05-2015 30-08-2015 **29-11-2015** 29-02-2016 30-05-2016

Do u have any idea that could help me?

Thanks :)

Comment: Can you provide an example? If the frequency is specified in months and not in days, I don't see how Actual/360 can be of relevance for this.

Comment: @Leviathan I already edited and explained better. It was wrong, the problem is not the basis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem regarding functions `COUPNCD` and `COUPNUM` – cannot use 12 (for monthly payments) as frequency attribute.

There is a way around – you can write the following user defined function. I use it now in my financial models, and it works perfectly.

```
Option Explicit
Public Function DC_CoupNum(Settlement As Date, Maturity As Date, NumberOfPayments As Integer) As Integer
    Dim NewDate As Date
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim r As Integer
    Select Case NumberOfPayments

        Case 1
            r = 12
        Case 2
            r = 6
        Case 4
            r = 3
        Case 12
            r = 1
    End Select

    NewDate = Maturity
    i = 0
    Do While NewDate > Settlement
        i = i + 1
        NewDate = Application.WorksheetFunction.EDate(NewDate, -1 * r)
'        Debug.Print NewDate
    Loop
    DC_CoupNum = i

End Function
Public Function DC_CoupNcd(Settlement As Date, Maturity As Date, Frequency As Integer, Optional NextC As Boolean = True) As Date
    'next coupon date after the settlement date

    'NextC = True ... next coupon date
    'NextC = False ... previous coupon date
    Dim m, o

    Select Case Frequency

        Case 1
            m = 12
        Case 2
            m = 6
        Case 4
            m = 3
        Case 12
            m = 1
    End Select

    o = DC_CoupNum(Settlement, Maturity, Frequency) - 1

    If NextC = False Then o = o + 1


    If Maturity = WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(Maturity, 0) Then 'pokud je Maturity konec mesice
        DC_CoupNcd = Application.WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(Maturity, -o * m)
    Else
        DC_CoupNcd = Application.WorksheetFunction.EDate(Maturity, -o * m)
    End If

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your `EDATE()` results. Using the following formula I get exactly the same values as you did for the `COUPNCD()` function:

```
=EDATE(maturity;0)    ==>  30-05-2016
=EDATE(maturity;-3)   ==>  29-02-2016
=EDATE(maturity;-6)   ==>  30-11-2015
=EDATE(maturity;-9)   ==>  30-08-2015
=EDATE(maturity;-12)  ==>  30-05-2015
=EDATE(maturity;-15)  ==>  28-02-2015
```

*(with `maturity` being 30-05-2016)*

Please check that you use the correct parameters for the `EDATE()` function, as indicated above.

Comment: I made it in a different way: 
=EDATE(maturity;-3) ==> A10
=EDATE(A10;-3) ==>A9
=EDATE(A9;-3) ==> A8
=EDATE(A8;-3) ==> A7

But your way solves my problem :) Thanks for the help.